# Is the point closest to origin in an intersection of hyperplanes unique

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have $k$ hyperplanes in $R^{n}$ with non-empty intersection. I'm trying to figure out if the point in this intersection that is closest to the origin unique. It makes sense that it would be unique but I'm having a hard time convincing myself. An answer/explanation would be most appreciated.

Comment: By hyperplane do you mean an $n-1$ dimensional subspace, or do you mean those and all of their translations (i.e. cosets)?

Comment: I should have said affine hyperplanes, anything of the form $H_{a,b}=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\ |\ a^{\top}x=b\right\}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$